# How to make a Round Robin? or Is there an easier way other than Round Robin?

Tags: php, mysql

The problem that I face is ***in what way*** if there is issue like the example below:

Codes 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000

ID 1, 2, 3

========================================

This:

**ID number 1 has codes 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000**

**ID number 2 has codes 2000, 4000, 3000**

**ID number 3 has codes 3000, 4000, 5000**

========================================

When all the fields are connected, each ID has found the same codes.
From the example above, I want to produce fair result and adjusted to the code that it had before on each ID as below: (producing fair codes over the set of ID's)

========================================

To be:

**ID number 1 has codes 1000, 2000** (1000 must be on number 1 cause only it has than other)

**ID number 2 has codes 3000, 4000**

**ID number 3 has codes 5000** (5000 must be on number 3 cause only it has than other)

========================================

Some say using **Round Robin**, but I never heard Round Robin before and I don't have idea how to use it, such a blank mind. 
Is there another easier way like to use PHP may be? I'm lost.

Thanks.

=============================================================

**Explanation**:

I'm making an application where each user has a predefined code and does not have the same code. For example user A has a range of codes between 1000-1500, the user B has a range of codes between 1600 to 2000. And user C has a range of codes between 1300-1550. As we see, the distance of a code on the C contained in the codes on the A (A -> 1000-1500, C -> 1300-1550), will certainly get duplicate between the two user.
With this condition, how to separate and divide it to make it more fair. Let C has 1300, A has 1301, C has 1302 et cetera until 1500.

I thought the simple example I gave before could quite understand, but it seemed like a mess, my mistake.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say the fields are 'connected', and IDs 'finding' codes or producing a 'fair' result. Could you explain these please?

Comment: Am I right to say that you want to fairly distribute codes over a set of id's?

Comment: @adomnom I'm sorry if you don't get it. Just as Jack said, I want to make fairly distribute codes over the set of ID's.

Comment: @Jack Yes, seem like that. I'm sorry for troubling you. Do you know how to make it? Cause I'm really lost.

Answer (score 3):

```
$codes = array(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000);

// set up the receiving "containers"
$ids = array(
  array(),
  array(),
  array(),
);

$n_ids = count($ids);
$i = 0;

foreach ($codes as $code) {
    // use ($i % $n_ids) to distribute over $n_ids containers
    $ids[$i % $n_ids][] = $code;
    ++$i;
}

print_r($ids);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1000
            [1] => 4000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2000
            [1] => 5000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3000
        )

)
```

This problem is a simple distribution task: Distribute N items over M containers.

For every `i` (0 <= `i` < `N`) you select a container to put item `N[i]` in; the selection is done by using this expression: `i mod M` (`i` modulo `M`).

This expression is what you could call the round-robin, because it goes round like this:

```
i    :  0  1  2  3  4
i % M:  0  1  2  0  1
```

### Even faster

The `array_chunk` function does this task as well, but I figured you would like to understand the problem first. Also, `array_chunk` produces a somewhat different result.

```
$ids = array_chunk(array(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000), round(count($codes) / 3));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1000
            [1] => 2000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3000
            [1] => 4000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5000
        )

)
```

Comment: @zerkms I figured I'd explain the problem first, but I've added `array_chunk` as well. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Jack I have thought to use modulo, just cannot how to use it. Could I get some codes from database into array? I mean, the array we know is array(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000) which is input manually, how if I call some codes from database which is not input manually (random) like array(codes from database)?

Comment: @candies if the codes come iteratively it's best to use the modulo method (first one); just change the `foreach` to iterate over your database results instead.

Comment: @Jack Oke, I've got the codes from database, but there is something wrong with ids. How many array() should I put into ids variable? -> $ids = array(array(),array(),array()) because there are many codes in the database.

Comment: @candies that depends on how many codes are you going to assign to each id ... maybe you could explain more about the background of your app, because it's a bit vague.